# Get all the values from the attributes set in a variable product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product-variations

In WooCommerce, I am trying to get all the values of a variable product independently of each other.

**For example:** 
I have the attribute size. 
Size has three values: size S, size M and size L. 
If the product has all the options for size, I want to see the product three times in my output:

- one time with size S,
- one time with size M
- and one time with size L.

With the following code I see which variations I have. Further i did not come unfortunately.

```
private function readOptions($product) {
    $variations = $product->get_children();
    foreach ($variations as $variation) {
        $single_variation=new WC_Product_Variation($variation);
        $this->doLog(print_r($single_variation->get_variation_attributes(), true));
    }              
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your function code here *(well commented)*:

```
private function readOptions($product) {

    // Get all attributes & values set in the product (product variations)
    $variation_attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();

    // iterating through each attribute
    foreach ($variation_attributes as $attribute_slug => $attribute_slug_values){

        // Getting the attribute object (the taxonomy object)
        $attribute_obj = get_taxonomy( $attribute_slug ); // Attribute name: $attribute_obj->label

        // Iterating through each attribute values set in the product
        foreach($attribute_slug_values as $attribute_slug_value){

            // Getting the object of the term value (and the name: $attr_value_obj->name)
            $attr_value_obj = get_term_by( 'slug', $attribute_slug_value, $attribute_slug );

            // Output the names of the product, the attribute and the value
            echo '<p>Product "'.$product->get_title().'" has attribute "'.$attribute_obj->label.'" with value "'.$attr_value_obj->name.'"</p>';
        }
    }          
}
```

You will get exactly what you are expecting.

> Here the output is just an example, but you get for each attribute and values set in the product:
>   The product + an attribute + a value *(for all attribute values set in it).*